# list view header about react native

Tags: react-native

I want to create a React Native demo that has a `ListView` header. Currently I'm just rendering a view on top of my `ListView` component:

```
render: function() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
        return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
            return (
               <View style = {styles.viewContainer}>
                    <Text style = {styles.title}>标题：{this.state.question.content}</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.year}>描述：{this.state.question.description}</Text>
                    <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderMovie}
                    style={styles.listView}/>
                </View>
            );
            //加载回复答案

},

renderLoadingView: function() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>
                Loading Infos...
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
},

renderMovie: function(movie) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.content}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.year}>id:{movie.username}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    },
});
```

I would like to render the header as a part of the `ListView` component instead. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React Native documentation on ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content), `ListView` can accept a `renderHeader` function as a prop and will render a header based on it.

Here's how you can do it:

```
render: function() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
        return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
            return (
               <View style = {styles.viewContainer}>
                    <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderMovie}
                    renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
                    style={styles.listView}/>
                </View>
            );
},

renderHeader: function() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style = {styles.title}>标题：{this.state.question.content}</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.year}>描述：{this.state.question.description}</Text>
        </View>
        )
}

renderLoadingView: function() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>
                Loading Infos...
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
},

renderMovie: function(movie) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.content}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.year}>id:{movie.username}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    },
});
```